# JSON response getting truncated with rather small array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, asp.net-core

On the controller method, before returning the value, result array is filled correctly. However, generated JSON response is truncated from start. This is on asp net core 2.1. I have one middleware block but doesn't get called while returning response, only in requests.

I already tried ReferenceLoopHandling option, didn't work, I am working on quite small array anyways.

```cs
[HttpGet("GetAll")]
public IEnumerable<Job> GetAll()
{
    var result = _dbManager.GetAllJobs();
    return result;
}
```

Response should be fully constructed Json array, however I am getting this:

```
[{
```

Comment: Map your Entity to DTO. That will solve your problem.

Comment: @YigitTanriverdi thanks, it did actually, but why?

Comment: Because your entity has relations and Asp.net core conflicting to serialize them. @Metin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map like that easily.

```
[HttpGet("GetAll")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
{
    var result = _dbManager.GetAllJobs();
    return Ok(result.Select(x=> new JobDto(){ Id = x.Id, JobName = x.Name ....}));
}
```